# Get data from two date ranges within same table (MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
  SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ProdTr.OrdNo) AS Orders, 
  ProdTr.YrPr AS Period, 
  SUM(ProdTr.DAm) AS Total, 
  SUM(ProdTr.IncCst) AS Cost 

  FROM ProdTr

  WHERE ProdTr.TrTp = 1 AND ProdTr.CustNo != 0 
  AND ProdTr.YrPr BETWEEN (201901) AND (201912)
  GROUP BY ProdTr.YrPr 
  ORDER BY ProdTr.YrPr ASC
```

And it works well. It yields the expected result, sales data from the date period 2019-01 to 2019-12. Result:

[image: Result]

I would like to add an extra column that shows the same data - but from last year. For period 2019-01 it should show sales data for 2018-01 (1 year back). I managed to do this with a subquery, but it is slow - and seems like a bad idea.

Are there any better ways to achieve this? Database version is MSSQL 2016.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Only 1 extra column for 2018? You have 4 columns for 2019.

Comment: Yes, correct. I only need the total sales (SUM(DAm)) from 2018 to compare sales progress and statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LEFT(YrPr, 4) = '2019' THEN OrdNo END) AS Orders2019, 
  '2019' + RIGHT(YrPr, 2) AS Period2019, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(YrPr, 4) = '2019' THEN DAm END) AS Total2019, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(YrPr, 4) = '2019' THEN IncCst END) AS Cost2019,
  SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(YrPr, 4) = '2018' THEN DAm END) AS Total2018 
FROM ProdTr
WHERE TrTp = 1 AND CustNo != 0 
  AND YrPr BETWEEN (201801) AND (201912)
GROUP BY RIGHT(YrPr, 2) 
ORDER BY Period2019 ASC
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great! It has one issue though, when the period is - let's say "YrPr BETWEEN 201902 AND 202002", it has some issues... :-)

Comment: This code works only for a full year period: 201901 up to 201912, like the requirement in your question.

Comment: Absolutely! It is the requirement. It was just information. Thank you for your time!

Comment: By the way, is it possible to add a join to a conditional aggregation like this? Example: LEFT JOIN Actor ON Actor.CustNo = ProdTr.CustNo, and Actor.Gr in GROUP BY.

Comment: Syntactically it's valid.

Comment: Thanks :) It yields 88 rows instead of 12 rows, as it lists every Gr value for each month. 201901 now consists of several rows. It also slows the query down quite a lot. Maybe this is better suited in a new question.

Comment: Don't expect 12 rows. There will be as many rows as the distinct combinations of RIGHT(YrPr, 2) and Actor.Gr

Comment: Exactly! However, is it possible to group the rows by period?

Comment: Any column that is returned by the joins can be used in the group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```sql
WITH TwoYears AS (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProdTr.OrdNo) AS Orders
         , ProdTr.YrPr AS Period
         , SUM(ProdTr.DAm) AS Total
         , SUM(ProdTr.IncCst) AS Cost
      FROM ProdTr
     WHERE ProdTr.TrTp = 1
       AND ProdTr.CustNo != 0
       AND ProdTr.YrPr BETWEEN 201801 AND 201912
     GROUP BY ProdTr.YrPr
), CurrentYear AS (
    SELECT Orders, Period, Total, Cost
      FROM TwoYears
     WHERE Period >= 201901
), PreviousYear AS (
    SELECT Orders, Period, Total, Cost
      FROM TwoYears
     WHERE Period < 201901
)
SELECT c.Orders, c.Period, c.Total, c.Cost
     , p.Orders AS PrevOrders, p.Period AS PrevPeriod, p.Total AS PrevTotal, p.Cost AS PrevCost
  FROM CurrentYear c
  FULL JOIN PreviousYear p ON p.Period = c.Period - 100
 ORDER BY COALESCE(c.Period, p.Period + 100)
```